# Left join table where the category has single value and product table has multiple categories in single column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables one has the categories

```
CID CategoryName CategoryURL

1      Games        /URL

2      Cars        /URL
```

etc

The other table is the products table which also has the CID

```
PID CID ProductName etc 

1   ,2,3 Honda 


1   ,3,4 Ford
```

My problem is that I need to do a left join to get the CID of the product but left join isn't working because the CID in the products has multiple values.

What should I do?

Comment: you can select top 1 from each CID

Comment: a solution might be possible, but better normalize your database, and choose appropriate data structures if you want no pain.

Comment: How can i select top 1 from each CID?

Comment: Fix your database design.

Comment: What LEFT JOIN? Its ALWAYS a database design error if you have a fields in your database with comma delimited data in it.